# Can Google's Invisible reCAPTCHA be used to protect an entire page (not form or button)?

Tags: javascript, redirect, recaptcha

For example, if you want to protect a webpage that can be opened by simply visiting a URL, not by submitting some form, can you use reCAPTCHA to prevent bots from seeing (scraping) it?

I imagine that would require the server to first show an empty page which does nothing but `grecaptcha.execute()` and then in case of success show the real page.

Is this a good way of doing it?

Comment: The way you suggest would still involve using a form.

Comment: That sounds like a login page. Just, without a username or password, but only using reCAPTHCA to authenticate you as a human being.

Comment: @szx Can you kindly check my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76348928/how-to-secure-a-page-using-recapcha-silently-for-scrappers My requirement is also to block the entire page if its try to scrapped by code not by a real browser. Seems no body is familiar with that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have two pages, one with the captcha on it and another one which displays the real content.

The second page would only be accessible with a POST request that must contain the correct captcha answer.

Basically, you would have an empty form on the first page, implemented exactly how you would do for a contact form or something. Just make sure the second page is accessible only you have the captcha answer in the request body. If not, then redirect to the first page with the captcha.

Comment: One problem: because you can only validate a ReCaptcha answer (known better as ReCaptcha response token) a single time when the user hits refresh on the second page (or navigates away and back) you will get an error from Google ReCaptcha service: "timeout-or-duplicate"

Comment: @fabio. Can you kindly check my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76348928/how-to-secure-a-page-using-recapcha-silently-for-scrappers My requirement is also to block the entire page if its try to scrapped by code not by a real browser. Seems no body is familiar with that. Thank you