# How to Secure a Page using Recapcha Silently For Scrappers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, recaptcha

I have a site where I display the specs of various products. For eg take televisions. I have all the specifications related to every TV. This page has lot of research data.

So when the user selects a tv model from a autocomplete, I display all the specifications in the page. So the pattern is same. So I want this page to be secure.

I know the scraping cant be prevented. But I want to prevent someone write a piece of code in c#,java or anything that provides a URL to a textbox and get the HTML code to an object ( Other than my site view in a real browser ) I want to send blank HTML or provide recpacha to view the specifications.

So far I did this.
In my layout.cshtml I referenced capcha script like below

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

At program.cs I added a section like this

```
builder.Services.AddReCaptcha(options =>
{
    options.SiteKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    options.SecretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXx";
    options.Version = ReCaptchaVersion.V2Invisible;
});
```

Also the place where I want to use this recapcha I included these code. in .cshtml

```
@using AspNetCore.ReCaptcha

@Html.ReCaptcha()
```

I did this according to below post
https://codeburst.io/implement-recaptcha-in-asp-net-core-and-razor-pages-eed8ae720933

But I couldn't get this to work. I want this to fire at page load.

For eg: If the user load the following URL other than a real browser, I want all the HTML to disappear or send recpacha challenge.

```
https://test.com/specs/1/panasonic-23inch
```

**For a scraper, he only needs a for loop to go through all the posts and necessary tags to grab the values of each parameter.**

So kindly help me.
But please note that this method should not block the Google bots or any other search engine bots for indexing. For your reference, here is a sample of my autocompletion.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("Search")',
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var label = ui.item.label;
                var value = ui.item.val;
                var slug = ui.item.slug;

                $('#compareone').val(value);
                $('#compareoneslug').val(slug);

                var getCompareTwo = $("#comparetwo").val();
                var getCompareTwoSlug = $("#comparetwoslug").val();

                var url = '/specs/' + value + '/' + $('#compareoneslug').val();

                if (getCompareTwo > 0) {
                    url = '/specs/' + value + '-' + getCompareTwo + '/' + slug + '-vs-' + getCompareTwoSlug;
                }
                window.location.href = url;
            }
        });
```

Another idea of mine is to capture the user agent, and if its a browser, then allow it otherwise don't

```
string userAgent = Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
```

Is this a good idea? Still I am on fence.

Comment: If there is no other solution, you can use the user agent to judge. But it is worth noting that you can use the user agent to determine whether it is a browser, but you should try to avoid using the user agent to determine which browser (for example: Edge or Google). Please check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) for more details.